# Ampscript: desc sort field values from data extension and pass them to another variable

Tags: sorting, exacttarget, ampscript

**I have a data extensions with 6 fields:**

```
EmailAdress (type: EmailAdress, unique)
Field1 (type: number, not nullable)
Field2 (type: number, not nullable)
Field3 (type: number, not nullable)
Field4 (type: number, not nullable)
Field5 (type: number, not nullable)
```

**I have 3 objectives:**


*1. Pass the values of each field into ampscript variables (the easy part)*

```
%%[
Set @var1 = Field1
Set @var2 = Field2
Set @var3 = Field3
Set @var4 = Field4
Set @var5 = Field5
]%%
```

*2. Sort the variables descending based on their values and (3) pass them on to one of the five contentareas.*

```
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\mainitem\@maxvar1")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem1\@maxvar2")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem2\@maxvar3")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem3\@maxvar4")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem4\@maxvar5")=%%
```

**If, for example the values of my fields are:**

```
Field1: 10
Field2: 15
Field3: 5
Field4: 1
Field5: 100
```

**Then my five contentareas should be populated as following:**

```
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\mainitem\@field5")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem1\@field2")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem2\@field1")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem3\@field3")=%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\Campaigns\subitem4\@field4")=%%
```

Passing the values to amscript values is very easy. But desc sorting them and passing them on the appropiate @maxvar seems to be a bit of a stretch for my limited ampscript knowledge.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question.  I'd unpivot your Data Extension with a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) and then use a [LookupOrderedRows()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupOrderedRows) function to retrieve them in the proper order.  Sorting is too much of a pain in AMPScript.

The T-SQL UNPIVOT() function won't work on ET/SFMC, so you'll need to do it the old-school way in your Query Activity:

```
select 
emailAddress
, field
, fieldValue
from [unpivot-test]
cross apply (
  select 'field1', field1 union all
  select 'field2', field2 union all
  select 'field3', field3 union all
  select 'field4', field4 union all
  select 'field5', field5
) c (field, fieldValue)
```

I have several AMPScript lookup examples on [my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).  Here's the LookupOrderedRows() one:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[

next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

**Also, post any future ET/SFMC questions over on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and tag them with `marketing-cloud`.  There's a lot more people asking/answering questions over there.**

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your comment! First I tried your sql in my query activity and I now have an DE that has five times the number of records of the original one. Each (previously unique) emailadress is now present 5 times in the new DE. Is that the expected output of the query?

Comment: Yes.  Now you can retrieve those rows by Email Address, ordered by your min/max criteria.